# Intellij Idea takes forever to show folders in "file/folder selector" dialog

Tags: windows, windows-10, java, intellij-idea

The naming similarities to [this unanswered SE Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938877/intellij-idea-takes-too-long-to-show-files-in-the-file-folder-selector-dialog) from 2016 are intentional. We have the exact same problem.

I am using IntelliJ Idea for Java work, but in a way that I frequently need to us the "*Create Module From Existing Sources*" feature that leans on the "*file/folder selector*" to input a folder for the new module. The problem is that it gets stuck like this:

[image: Issue]

This leaves Intellij entirely unusable while it spins in circles, loading, for a good minute or so. Looking at Task Manager, it is clear that nothing special is happening.

[image: Task manager]

This isn't damaging, it's just an extremely jarring nuisance that I'd like to see gone. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Do you have network shares which might be unavailable or slow to respond? Try also to temporarily disable your antivirus.

Comment: Ah. Network shares might account for this... Is there any way that I could exclude them from the search or similar? I work away from my home network where the shares I have are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network shares might be responsible for this problem when the computer is used
away from that network.

I don't know of a way to start a program and hide from it such network shares.

However, it should be easy to setup batch scripts with the
[net use command](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)
to delete the shares and recreate them when needed.

To avoid entering passwords again and again, look into the `/SAVECRED` option
of the command.

Alternatively, just create the shares with the script whenever needed, but as
non-persistent, and they will not exist when you boot again.
This way, you will only need one script.

Comment: Ooh. I like that. Do you know if there is a way to detect which WiFi network I'm on in a batch script?

Comment: Excellent, I created a [batch script to do this](https://github.com/neilbalch/Configurations/blob/master/Windows/SMBShares.cmd). I'll see if it works at school tomorrow.